# Ошибка (The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly )при запуске Tomcat в Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Ошибка выглядит так:

> The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В системных переменных:

```
JRE_HOME = C:\jre1.8
CLASSPATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\lib
CATALINA_HOME = E:\tomee7.0.2
JAVA_HOME = C:\jdk1.8
```

Если запускать файл `E:\tomee7.0.2\bin\start.bat` вручную, то он запускается и http://localhost:8080/ показывает страницу *Tomcat*.

Почему же в *Idea* возникает ошибка? Может, `JRE_HOME` надо куда-то в нее прописать?

Answer (score 1):

все оказалось очень просто - надо было вместо default указать путь к JRE
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]